# Get filename from proxy response when write to file in OSB

Tags: osb, oracle-service-bus

I want to make a OSB service that asks for a file on another service (URI) and store the received file to a specific location. I managed to make the request and have the response from the external service, and now I want to store the file with a BS over a JCA Connector by writing the binary on the local disk (for instance).
I'm calling the BS from the Proxy with a Publish component. My problem is that I don't know how to pass the filename from the response in proxy to JCA through the Publish and BS.
Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understand is you have the file name in your proxy but not able pass it to jca. Here is what you have to do -

1. Inside you publish activity, place a 'Transport Header' activity.
2. Set direction to `Outbound Request`.
3. Set protocol to `jca`.
4. Set `jca.file.FileName` and `jca.file.Directory` to the values that you have in proxy.